Religiously confused
I was adopted into a Jewish family, never felt I belonged . Had a troubled childhood, my adopted dad stuck me in a school that trained kids to become rabbis. The school wanted me to get bar mitzvahed,however because they could not verify my religon would not and as a result was kicked out of the school. Now for the most part have been dead to my adopted family. See I want nothing more than to please God , not sure what to believe in. Don't like the idea of ending up in hell for all eternity. What am I supposed to do , feel , believe in?

While this isn’t even close to an all encompassing answer, I would tell you that if you may not know tonight begins the holiday of Passover, a holiday that celebrates our freedom and redemption, both national and personal, from Egypt. Symbolically, this would be a perfect time for you as well to get in touch with your heritage. Perhaps contact a local rabbi in your community, such as one associated with Chabad, and they’d be more than happy to help set you up with an uplifting and inspiring meal tonight. Good luck my friend

This question is unfortunately not for this site. You need to speak to someone who can get to know you and your situation, and despite the fact that the people upon whom that responsibility fell on shirked it, that doesn't mean there aren't many others who would gladly assist you. Please find your nearest orthodox Rabbi (and if those are the ones that let you down, go further, or try your local Chabad house) and get on with discovering if you are Jewish, and if not make the decision to convert, or adopt the Noahide laws. Either way, you won't end up in hell for all eternity!!!!!!!
